# React router dom v6 - RequireAuth, ProtectedRoute , navigate(-1) need to press 2 time when refresh page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, browser-history

So I'm using React with `react-router-dom@6.3`. Here is what my project flow look like.
I have a `authRoutes` (public route) and a `cmsRoutes` (protected route).

```
const cmsRoutes: RouteObject[] = [
  { path: '/', element: <DashboardContainer /> },
]

const CmsRender = () => useRoutes(cmsRoutes);

const authRoutes: RouteObject[] = [
  {
    path: '/*',
    element: (
      <RequireAuth>
        <CmsLayout />
      </RequireAuth>
    ),
    caseSensitive: true,
  }
]
```

This is my `<App/>` file it render a container

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter>
          <TheContainer />
        </HashRouter>
      </Provider>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};
```

`TheContainer` then render the `authRoute` (public route)

```
const loading = (
  <div className="pt-3 text-center">
    <div className="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
  </div>
);

const TheContent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { token } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.authentication);

  useEffect(() => {
    let tempToken = token;
    if (!tempToken) {
      tempToken = localStorage.getItem('authentication_token');
    }

    if (tempToken) {
      // get current user info
      dispatch(fetching());
      dispatch(account());
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={loading}>
      <RouteRender />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default React.memo(TheContent);
```

The path "/" will route to `<TheContent/>` Component where i render the `cmsRoutes`(Protected Route)

```
const loading = (
  <div className="pt-3 text-center">
    <div className="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
  </div>
);

const TheContent = () => {
  return (
    <CContainer fluid className="px-0">
      <Suspense fallback={loading}>
        <CmsRender />
      </Suspense>
    </CContainer>
  );
};

export default React.memo(TheContent);
```

Before render the `cmsRoutes` the code will go through the `<RequireAuth/>` Component.
If the user is login it will render `cmsRoutes` other wise it will redirect the user to the `<Login/>` component and also send the current location with it through the `state={{ path: location.pathname }}`.

```
interface IRequireAuthProp {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const RequireAuth = ({ children }: IRequireAuthProp) => {
  const { location } = useRouter();
  const { user } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.authentication);

  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ path: location.pathname }} />;
  }

  return <>{children}</>;
};
```

Here is my `<Login/>` component. So if user login success it will redirect user to the `cmsRoutes`. If the state url exist it will redirect to that url and then replace the url in the history stack

```
interface ILocationPath {
  path?: string
}
  
const Login = () => {
  const { navigate, location } = useRouter()
  const state = location.state as ILocationPath
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      const statePath = state?.path || '/'
      const redirectPath = statePath.includes('login') ? '/' : statePath
      navigate(redirectPath, { replace: true })
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [user])

  return (
    <>Login logic</>
  )
}
  
export default Login
```

HERE'S THE PROBLEM:
When I enter a page in the `cmsRoutes` eg: I'm in the `Manage` page with a table of users, then I redirect to a `Detail` page of a user. In the `Detail` page have a button `onClick` `navigate(-1)` to redirect back to the previous page, everything work fine. Until I refresh (f5) the page. Because of the above flow my web then will go through the `<RequireAuth />` component first but that moment it does not find user exist it will redirect to the `<Login />`. In the `<Login />` the code find the user does exist then it will redirect back to the `Detail` page. Every time it will add the `"/login"` path to the history stack, because I use `replace: true` the stack will replace the `"/login"` path with the path of the `Detail` page. Every time the page refresh (f5) the history stack will add more of the `Detail` page then the `navigate(-1)` will have to go through all the `Detail` page have been stack before go back to the `Manage` page. If I don't use `replace: true` then the `navigate(-1)` will go back to the `<Login />` and the `<Login />` then redirect back to the current page it will be a loop back and forth. So any idea how to resolve this or do you guys use another way to redirect with protected route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to fix is to actually redirect to `"/login"` for unauthenticated users. Instead of a PUSH navigation action it should be a REPLACE navigation action. This will help maintain the history stack.

```
export const RequireAuth = ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
  const { location } = useRouter();
  const { user } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.authentication);

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <Navigate
        to="/login"
        replace // <-- redirect
        state={{ path: location.pathname }}
      />
    );
  }

  return <>{children}</>;
};
```